# MS Filters added with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background

I'm working on a project and one of tasks is to make the background static and cover whole page.  About this I found [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/), using "Awesome, Easy, Progressive CSS3 Way".  My problem is that I have more pages and each has a different background so I have to put the background image on `<body>` like this:

```
<body style="background-image:url(images/mainBg_1.jpg);">
```

(also the css style is put on `<body>`, not on "html", like in example)

As you can see in that link, there are filters for IE, like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.**myBackground.jpg**', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='**myBackground.jpg**', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

The problem is that "myBackground.jpg" is taken from `<body>` tag, as I wrote above, so I can't write directly in css (every page has different background).

Is there a way to add these filters using jQuery?  I successfully took the path of the image from body, so I only need to paste it in this code and then add with jQuery for IE <= 8.

Thanks for your answers, following them i succeed to solve my problem. So, if somebody wants the code :

```
$(function(){       
    var mu = $.browser;
    if (mu.msie && mu.version < 9) {

        var curBg = $('html').attr('style');
        curBg = curBg.split('(');
        curBg = curBg[1].split(')'); 

        $('html').css({
                    "filter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+curBg[0]+"', sizingMethod='scale')",
                    "-ms-filter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+curBg[0]+"', sizingMethod='scale')"
            });         

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you see any codes of yours here? You said... 'like this' ... nothing shows up!  Enclose your codes into `  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use $('body').css() or $('body').attr() and change the style attribute of body.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Tanks for your answer. I had some knowledge about these functions but i wasn't sure how to use this in that case. Right now i succeed so everything looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

Test this way
it could be something like:

You add in your page a hidden `img` element that contains your desired image

```
<img class="myBgImage" src="images/mainBg_1.jpg" style="display:none"/>
```

You grab the image `src` from that image class name

```
var bgImage = $('img.myBgImage').attr('src');

$('body').append("<style>body{progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+bgImage+"', sizingMethod='scale'); -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=' "+ bgImage +"', sizingMethod='scale')';}</style>");
```

And you append to body the css IE fix having for BG-image the VAR holding the img `src` url.

Just an idea.

Comment: It is better to add the styles to the head, not the body.

Comment: Your idea was good but didn't follow the right way. Also I put the image on the html.